# When will I get daily challenges for V-bucks in STW?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

I recently started playing Fortnite:Save The World. My friend told me there were daily challenges worth V-bucks and Gold. However, I am unable to see any in the (Quests tab). I am at the ***3rd Storm Shield defense(Not completed yet)***.

**Can someone please tell me if this is a bug, or when will I unlock daily challenges for STW for V-bucks and Gold?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get them after SSD 3. You'll get 50 vBucks a day, plus 100 daily coins that can be spent in the shop.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer accept, I didn't see it in my notifications.